# if x=10 y=10 z=5 how is x<y<z=true?

Tags: c, compare

I have this question & in the answer it says that due to left to right associativity the result would be 1 that is true for this statement. This is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
int i=0,x=10,y=10,z=5;
i=x<y<z;
printf("\n\n%d",i);

return 0;
}
```

But x is greater than z here so how is this happening ?

Comment: x<y<z in C is not what you think it is. It doesn't allow compound comparison statements.

Comment: What are you trying to do?can you please elaborate.

Comment: It was asked in an exam & I am trying to figure it out how is this happening @DakshShah

Comment: (`x<y` => `10 < 10` => `0`) => `0 < z` => `0 < 5` => true, change to `x < y && y < z`

Comment: First of all I think its very bad practice to compare variables like this(three variables at a time). It is displaying one as output because its checking (x<y) first and then comparing output of the former with z. x<y gives 0 and 0<5 gives 1.

Comment: I think we need a few more people exhibiting identical answers, Surely the OP isn't going to reach an understanding until there are at least a dozen down there.

Comment: @WhozCraig, right, that should have been obvious, right *after* the first 3-4 answers popped within a few seconds of each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression x

```
(x < y) < z
```

so it becomes

```
(10 < 10) < 5
```

which further is evaluated into

```
0 < 5
```

which is true.

I think you wanted something like this:

```
x < y && y < z
```

Comment: He doesn't "want" anything, he said it was an exam question asking why the original code has this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Because of operator precedence and associativity

```
i = x < y < z;
```

is parsed as:

```
i = ((x < y) < z);
```

After substituting the variable values, this becomes:

```
i = ((10 < 10) < 5);
```

Since `10 < 10` is false, this becomes:

```
i = (0 < 5);
```

Since `0 < 5` is true, that becomes:

```
i = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`x<y<z` is not a single valid expression. Instead it evaluates `x<y` first ([operator precedence](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) is done left to right here) as true/false (false in this case as they're equal), converts it to an int value of `0`, and then compares this value with `z`.

Use `(x < y && y < z)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It first evaluates `x < y` which is false (0), then `0 < z` which is true (1).

Answer (score 1):

WHat C compiler does is, in `x<y<z`;
starts from left, so as x is not less than y therefore it replaces that expression with '0'
so it becomes `0<z` and as that is true. it set the variable to 1.